# uibutton onclick does not call/open web page

Tags: iphone, uibutton

i have two buttons defined. one of them when clicked must open a compose mail screen and the other when clicked must call. i have this defined as below. but when the button is pressed, it does not open either

```
-(IBAction) phoneButtonPressed:(id) sender{
    NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"4216483330"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
}

-(IBAction) mailButtonPressed:(id) sender{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:askalibrarian@mail.pitt.edu?subject=ULS Library"]];  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the phone#, the url should be prefixed with "tel:" like this:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"tel:4216483330"];
```

For the mail, the problem is you have a space in the url string (in "ULS Library") which needs to be escaped before giving it to NSURL:

```
NSString *urlString = @"mailto:askalibrarian@mail.pitt.edu?subject=ULS Library";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString 
        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

See the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Also, you should release phoneNumber after the openURL line.

Comment: thanks..this thing worked... but is there a way for confirmation that I can ask user? Do you want to call? Do you want to send a mail?   could you please tell me how do i do that

Comment: You can use a UIAlertView or UIActionSheet depending on what look you want.  You would show the alertview/actionsheet in your IBAction methods and execute the openURL in the clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method of the alertview/actionsheet (if "OK/Yes" button was clicked).  The Apple sample app UICatalog has examples and there should be many on this site as well.